# Command Line Command to list Certain Records in Apache Log FIle

Tags: apache, list, logging

I want to list a block of records in an apache access log file. I know how to use tail -x but I want to list certain records from within the file and not just the end of it.

What might the command line command look like for this?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you determine those "certain records"?

Comment: @Pekka - trying to hone in on access records from 8am to 9am this morning. But I would be willing to do something like > "list 17500-18000 /log/file/name" if that would get me to a block of records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use `grep` to search the log file and specify a regex to match the desired time range?

For example, if your log entries use the time format DD/MMM/YYYY:HH:MM:SS, this command would print entries for Dec. 6th, 2011, from 8:00 to 8:59am.

```
grep '06/Dec/2011:08' logfile
```

Comment: Good stuff. To page through the results just pipe the output to the program less. Eg.: grep '06/Dec/2011:08' logfile | less.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 17500,18000p filename.txt
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @KingCrunch. I take it the "p" represents pause...how to you page through results?

Comment: `p` means "print". Like many things in the linux world you use a different tool ("One tool for one task") for paging: `sed -n 17500,18000p filename.txt | less`